# Sync Framework - Conflict Resolution Triggers Change, Resulting in Unnecessary Downloads

Tags: microsoft-sync-framework

I'm using Sync Framework v2.1 configured in a hub <--> spoke fashion.
Hub: SQL Server 2012 using SqlSyncProvider.
Spokes: LocalDb 2012 using SqlSyncProvider. Each spokes' database begins as a restored backup from the server, after which PostRestoreFixup is executed against it. In investigating this, I've also tried starting with an empty spoke database whose schema and data are created through provisioning and an initial, download-only sync.

Assume two spokes (A & B) and a central hub (let's call it H). They each have one table with one record and they're all in sync.

1. Spoke A changes the record and syncs, leaving A & H with identical records.
2. Spoke B changes the same record and syncs, resulting in a conflict with the change made in step #1. B's record is overwritten with H's, and H's record remains as-is. This is the expected/desired result. However, the SyncOperationStatistics returned by the orchestrator suggest changes are made at H. I've tried both SyncDirectionOrder directions, with these results:

   > ```
   > - DownloadAndUpload (H's local_update_peer_timestamp and last_change_datetime are updated) -->
   >     * Download changes total: 1
   >     * Download changes applied: 1
   >     * Download changed failed: 0
   >     * Upload changes total: 1
   >     * Upload changes applied: 1
   >     * Upload changed failed: 0
   >
   > - UploadAndDownload (H's local_update_peer_timestamp is updated)-->
   >     * Upload changes total: 1
   >     * Upload changes applied: 1
   >     * Upload changed failed: 0
   >     * Download changes total: 1
   >     * Download changes applied: 1
   >     * Download changed failed: 0
   > ```
3. And, indeed, when Spoke A syncs again the record is downloaded from H, even though H's record hasn't changed. Why?

The problem arising from this is, for example, if Spoke A makes another change to the record between steps #2 and 3, that change will (falsely) be flagged as a conflict and will be overwritten at step #3.

Here's the pared-down code demonstrating the issue or, rather, my question. Note that I've implemented the provider's ApplyChangeFailed handlers such that the server wins, regardless of the SyncDirectionOrder:

```
private const string ScopeName = "TestScope";
private const string TestTable = "TestTable";

public static SyncOperationStatistics Synchronize(SyncEndpoint local,SyncEndpoint remote, EventHandler<DbSyncProgressEventArgs> eventHandler)
{
    using (var localConn = new SqlConnection(local.ConnectionString))
    using (var remoteConn = new SqlConnection(remote.ConnectionString))
    {
        // provision the remote server if necessary
        //
        var serverProvision = new SqlSyncScopeProvisioning(remoteConn);
        if (!serverProvision.ScopeExists(ScopeName))
        {
            var serverScopeDesc = new DbSyncScopeDescription(ScopeName);
            var serverTableDesc = SqlSyncDescriptionBuilder.GetDescriptionForTable(TestTable, remoteConn);
            serverScopeDesc.Tables.Add(serverTableDesc);
            serverProvision.PopulateFromScopeDescription(serverScopeDesc);
            serverProvision.Apply();
        }

        // provision locally (localDb), if necessary, bringing down the server's scope
        //
        var clientProvision = new SqlSyncScopeProvisioning(localConn);
        if (!clientProvision.ScopeExists(ScopeName))
        {
            var scopeDesc = SqlSyncDescriptionBuilder.GetDescriptionForScope(ScopeName, remoteConn);
            clientProvision.PopulateFromScopeDescription(scopeDesc);
            clientProvision.Apply();
        }

        // create\initialize the sync providers and go for it...
        //
        using (var localProvider = new SqlSyncProvider(ScopeName, localConn))
        using (var remoteProvider = new SqlSyncProvider(ScopeName, remoteConn))
        {
            localProvider.SyncProviderPosition = SyncProviderPosition.Local;
            localProvider.SyncProgress += eventHandler;
            localProvider.ApplyChangeFailed += LocalProviderOnApplyChangeFailed;

            remoteProvider.SyncProviderPosition = SyncProviderPosition.Remote;
            remoteProvider.SyncProgress += eventHandler;
            remoteProvider.ApplyChangeFailed += RemoteProviderOnApplyChangeFailed;

            var syncOrchestrator = new SyncOrchestrator
            {
                LocalProvider = localProvider,
                RemoteProvider = remoteProvider,
                Direction = SyncDirectionOrder.UploadAndDownload // also issue with DownloadAndUpload
            };

            return syncOrchestrator.Synchronize();
        }
    }
}

private static void RemoteProviderOnApplyChangeFailed(object sender, DbApplyChangeFailedEventArgs e)
{
    // ignore conflicts at the server
    //
    e.Action = ApplyAction.Continue;
}

private static void LocalProviderOnApplyChangeFailed(object sender, DbApplyChangeFailedEventArgs e)
{
    // server wins, force write at each client
    //
    e.Action = ApplyAction.RetryWithForceWrite;
}
```

To reiterate, using this code along w/the configuration described at the outset, conflicting rows are, as expected, overwritten on the spoke containing the conflict and the server's version of that row remains as-is (unchanged). However, I'm seeing that each conflict results in an update to the server's xxx_tracking table, specifically the local_update_peer_timestamp and last_change_datetime fields. This, I'm guessing, results in a download to every other spoke even though the server's data hasn't really changed. This seems unnecessary and is, to me, counter-intuitive.

Comment: can you post the actual sync code with the sync direction in your test? in your item 2, the destination is that one that's overwritten with data from the source. the source should not have been updated. likewise, afaik, the last_change_datetime is not actually updated (check the triggers/stored procs created by sync and you'll see whether its being updated)

Comment: Hi, JuneT. Your idle thoughts have been super helpful and are much appreciated. Thank you. OK, I've amended my question per your comments. FYI, [xxx_tracking].[last_change_datetime] is updated to GETDATE() via the insert/update/delete triggers created by the Sync Framework, though upon further investigation I don't think this is related to the issue we're discussing here.

Comment: A potential work-around for this issue (when using SyncDirectionOrder.DownloadAndUpload, for example) is to cache the IDs of all conflicts resolved with RetryWithForceWrite and subsequently remove them from the server's DataSet in its ChangesSelected event. This prevents the server (called 'H' in my example) updates that happen in Step #2, which prevents the unnecessary download in Step #3. Not being a sync expert, I'm concerned there are side-effects with this approach that I've yet to discover but will surely bite me later.